# Working with two classes? Method error in one of them

Tags: java, class, object, methods

So basically I have to print out the worker's name in reverse, and loop through the string character by character. This is what I have for that method under Worker.java:

```
public String printRev(String fName) {

    for (int i = 0; i < fName.length(); i++) {
           fName = fName.charAt(i) + fName;     
    }
    return fName;
}
```

And for UseWorker.java I have:

```
anil.printRev();
jasmin.printRev();
fred.printRev();
```

But it's giving me the error message: "The method printRev(String) in the type Worker isn't applicable for the arguments ()."

It's also worth mentioning that I am not allowed to modify UseWorker, only Worker.

How can I go about fixing the problem?

Comment: `printRev` expects a `String` argument

Comment: As the error mentions, the method `printRev(String)` requires a `String` argument, but in `UseWorker.java` you are calling it with no arguments `printWorker()`. Try calling it like `printWorker("SomeName");`. Also your reverse method will not work properly.

Comment: You need to pass a `String` when calling `printRev()`. e.g. -> `jasmin.printRev(// String here);`

Comment: If you don't print anything in the method it should not be called printRev. You should either print the new name at the end instead returning it or rename the metod to getRev.

Comment: Your error message is pretty self-explicit. Your method printRev takes as argument a String you then need to use a string when you call it, e.g.: `printRev(name)`. You should then figure out a way to get a string without passing it as an argument into your method since it's the only file you can modify.

Comment: I can't modify the UseWorker class

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

1. When you call `printRev` you give no argument and it expects a `String`
2. The string you create will certainly not be the one you expect. You need the concatenate the characters from the **end** to the **beginning** without keeping your old value.
3. The naming is incorrect: you don't print anything. Rename it to `revert()` or `getReverted()`

Here is a fix proposal:

```
public String getReverted(String fName) {
    StringBuilder revName = new StringBuilder(fName.length());
    for (int i = fName.length(); i >0; i--) {
           revName.append(fName.charAt(i - 1));     
    }
    return revName.toString();
}
```

...and you call it this way :

```
System.out.println(anil.printRev("string to revert"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, by declaring function like this `public String printRev(String fName)` you are saying "I want a function with a name `printRev` which returns instance of `String` and takes one argument of type `String` (and has `public` access, but that is irrelevant for now).

Statement `anil.printRev();` means "Take object from variable `anil` and call function with name `printRev` and zero arguments on it. The thing is, there is no such method defined, as you defined it as a method with one argument.

What you probably meant to do is `printRev("Anil");` which means "Take a method with name `printRev` and one argument of type `String`, feed the `"Anil"` object (string) to its first argument and execute it."

Also, the rev function won't work as you expect it to. You are adding a char to `fName` all the time and then reading from it as if it was unchanged. You need to make a copy and add characters to the copy. Like this

```
public String printRev(String fName) {

    String reversed = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < fName.length(); i++) {
           reversed = fName.charAt(i) + reversed;     
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

(Please note that this method could be optimized further, but is out of scope of this question)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can't modify UseWorker.java, so you will have to make changes to your other class. Currently your method expects a String to be passed as an argument but clearly the Useworker class does not want you passing any arguments.
For this, you will have to create an fName in the class that you can modify.
For example,if your class is say Person, try:

```
public class Person{
    String fName;

    public Person(String fName){
        this.fName = fName;
    }

   public String printRev(){
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < fName.length(); i++) {
            result = fName.charAt(i) + result;     
        }
        return result;
   }
}
```